# Use WSE 3 web service without altering app.config

Tags: c#, web-services

I had to add WSE 3 to my .net 2.0 application because a web service I consume has been changed to send MTOM. I finally got it all working, but I dislike the changes I had to make to the app.config file.

Since there are nearly one thousand installations of my program, I have to worry about changing the config file during the next update.

Is there any way to set these settings in code?

```
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionImporterTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Description.WseExtensionImporter, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </soapExtensionImporterTypes>
    </webServices>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <microsoft.web.services3>
    <messaging>
      <mtom clientMode="On" />
    </messaging>
  </microsoft.web.services3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I found out that:

`<mtom clientMode="On">`

is exactly the same as the

`WebServicesClientProtocol.RequireMtom` property. No hint in MSDN whatsoever.